# How do I resolve an error about AM_PROG_LIBTOOL when building libopus from git?

Tags: build, autoconf

I've downloaded [libopus](http://git.xiph.org/?p=opus.git) from git and tried to build it, however I get,

```
Updating build configuration files, please wait....
configure.ac:38: warning: macro 'AM_PROG_LIBTOOL' not found in library
configure.ac:38: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to install libtool, which provides the necessary macros. On Ubuntu,

```
apt-get install libtool
```

Comment: This resolved the exact same problem for me while running FreeBSD. Thanks!